# Issue when trying to update clients info

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having an issue where when I go to upload or update a client, it will automatically take the clients profile off if you do not add an image to upload. But If I just want to update their website or motto, and click update, I don't want to have to try and search their image down again and upload it just to update a few items. Any Ideas on why it's doing this? Thank You In Advance.

Heres my code:

```
 <?php
        //Gets The Users info when editing it.
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM sponsors WHERE id='.$id);
    $stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
     $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        extract($row);
}

?>  





 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">

                  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="sponsor_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sponsor Name:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sponsor_name" id="sponsor_name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="sponsor_phone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sponsor Phone Number:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sponsor_phone" id="sponsor_phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">
                                            </div>
                                            </div>  
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="sponsor_moto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sponsors Motto:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sponsor_motto" id="sponsor_motto" value="<?php echo $motto;?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="sponsors_website" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sponsors Website:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sponsor_website" id="sponsor_website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="sponsor_on" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Sponsor on or off?:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sponsor_on" id="sponsor_on" value="<?php echo $live;?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">

                                <label for="image" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> Profile Picture </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">                              
                                <p><img id="image" src="../images/sponsors/<?php echo $row['logo'];?>" height="150" width="150" /></p>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image" accept="image/*" />
                                    </div>          
<br>
<br>                                    
                                      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
 <button type="submit" name="btn_save_updates" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light">Update Sponsor</button>                            
  <a  href="blue/deletesponsor.php?delete_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" /><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-rounded btn-danger" title="click for delete" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Sponsor?')">Delete Sponsor</button></a>
                                     </div>


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

Heres my PHP code that will update the Database.

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_GET['edit_id']) && !empty($_GET['edit_id']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
        $stmt_edit = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM sponsors WHERE id =:uid');
        $stmt_edit->execute(array(':uid'=>$id));
        $edit_row = $stmt_edit->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        extract($edit_row);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ../../login.php");
    }
    if(isset($_POST['btn_save_updates']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];       
        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];
        if($imgFile)
        {
            $upload_dir = '../images/sponsors/';
            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
            $userprofile = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions))
            {           
                if($imgSize < 5000000) 
                {
                    unlink($upload_dir.$edit_row['logo']);
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userprofile);
                }
                else
                {
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, Your File Is Too Large To Upload. It Should Be Less Than 5MB.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF Extension Files Are Allowed.";      
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $userprofile = $edit_row['userprofile'];
        }
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $sponsorname = $_POST['sponsor_name'];
            $motto = $_POST['sponsor_motto'];
            $phone = $_POST['sponsor_phone'];
            $website = $_POST['sponsor_website'];
            $son = $_POST['sponsor_on'];

            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE sponsors SET name=:sname, motto=:smotto, phone=:sphone,website=:swebsite,live=:son, logo=:upic WHERE id=:uid');
            $stmt->bindParam(':sname',$sponsorname);
            $stmt->bindParam(':smotto',$motto);
            $stmt->bindParam(':sphone',$phone);
            $stmt->bindParam(':swebsite',$website);
            $stmt->bindParam(':son',$son);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userprofile);
            $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                ?>
                <script>
                alert('Successfully Updated...');
                window.location.href='managesponsors.php?action=sponsorupdated';
                </script>
                <?php
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry User Could Not Be Updated!";
            }
        }           
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$errMSG = "Sorry User Could Not Be Updated!";` - You need to get the real error instead.

Comment: "automatically take the clients profile off".  What exactly does that mean?  Are you saying the record gets deleted?  Or ...?

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes the Record gets updated with nothing. The Row is blank.

Comment: So what you mean is that any fields that you don't put data in get emptied.

Comment: yes. So if I don't choose an Image it will automatically empty it.

Comment: One option would be to use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in your `UPDATE`. The downside with that though, is that you can't intentionally empty a field by deleting the value in the form.  You would need to add functionality to specifically delete the content.  Another option would be to add a checkbox or something where the user has to indicate that they want to upload the image field.  Then, you only run the update to that db column when the box is checked.  What you cannot do is pre-populate the image field.

Comment: *Face Palm.* I know why It was emptying the field. I had the wrong field name. `$userprofile = $edit_row['userprofile'];` should of been `$userprofile = $edit_row['logo'];` Its now updating with out deleting the image/field